# fail to compile SHA1( ) function in gcc. c languge

Tags: c, linux, string, gcc

Here is my code:

```
#include "openssl/sha.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"

unsigned char *SHA1(const unsigned char *d, unsigned long n, unsigned char *md);

int main(void)
{
  char data[] = "Hello, world!";

  size_t length = sizeof(data);

  unsigned char hash[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];

  SHA1(data, length, hash);

  return 0;
}
```

When I compile it with gcc without the `-Wall` option, the program run well and print out some string. When I use `-Wall`, I get the following situation:

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:

test.c:11:3: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 1 of ‘SHA1’ differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]

   SHA1(data, length, hash);
   ^
In file included from test.c:1:0:

/usr/include/openssl/sha.h:126:16: note: expected ‘const unsigned char *’ but argument is of type ‘char *’

 unsigned char *SHA1(const unsigned char *d, size_t n, unsigned char *md);

Can anyone help me, Thanks in advance.
```

Answer (score 3):

Your program doesn't fail to compile, it produces a warning.

In this case, SHA1 expects you to pass an `unsigned char*`, but you're passing a `char *`, you can safely convert the char* to an `unsigned char*`, so just do

```
SHA1((unsigned char*)data, length, hash);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now it could compile correctly.